# Is there a way to send content from my app, which is not from my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a theoretical question to the file system/restriction from `iOS`.
In an `Android` app I can open a file from filesystem, with my app, and send it via mail or send it to a `REST-service`.
This is not possible under `iOS`, because there is no filesystem like under `Android`.
As far as I know I can only send file, which are created by my app.

Is there a way to send content from my app, which is not from my app? 
For example a pdf received per mail, opened in my app and send it to a server or something else.

best regards

Comment: The short answer is yes, you can send files received in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make your app eligible to open specific type of files ( images, videos, pdf, docs, etc )

see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

After that you bring the url file and you can work on it locally into your app, or uploading the linked file on a server as well

Comment: Thanks, thats waht I am looking for.